# preserve filter state in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies

I've a razor view that shows some jobs data on the basis of some filter like date, description, city, country etc. etc. Data loads in grid and then user can open that specific job.

[image: Job]

when user clicks to view some job, it redirects on another page. what I want is that when user comes back on this page again, it should have preserved selected filter and searched data accordingly. I tried `tempdata` but is of no use. Then i tried `cookies` but it does not allow me to keep object as it always wants a string as a value.

Any guesses please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the browser local storage and some javascript code before sending the query to your server.

In the event that trigger the query, just collect the data and store it like this with javascript:

```
function myFunctionToBeCallBeforeSendingTheQuery() {
    var query = {
        jobTitle: 'user typed text goes here',
        countryId: 'the id goes here'
    }
    localStorage.setItem('query', query);
}
```

When the user come back to the page you need to execute the following javascript code after the page get loaded:

```
$(function() {
    var query = localStorage.getItem('query');
    if(query != null) {
         // here you set the fields of your form with the preview stored data.
    }
});
```